# How to open a local application(eg Self Service Portal) using teams app. I'm using bot framework v4 for development and its a chatbot Project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

Team,

I want to open locally deployed application from MS teams. All users have this application(eg Notepad, Notepad++ or Self Service Portal) installed in their computer, I just want my teams app to open this on button click as it is one of the requirement in our project.

Comment: Please have a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-first-app-overview) which will help you.

Comment: Hello @VaraPrasad-MSFT, The link posted by you is just an overview on creating apps for Microsoft Teams and nowhere related to my question. Our app is already launched on MS Teams and working fine. We have a new requirement which I need to address, tried to get solution but so far no success.

Comment: You can use the deeplink to open the app within the teams,  can you please try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab)